# How to stretch fields horizontally in jasperreport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports with Eclipse Plugin in a Java project.

In JasperReports I'd like to stretch a field horizontally and move the next element to the right if the text field is too long.

Even if I set all the elements with position float nothing happens.

If I set the text field with `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` I get vertical stretch, like this.

[image]

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
1   X   11111   Campo di Testo
1   X   12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890  Campo di Testo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Amongalen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4949750/amongalen) says in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704997/5292302) there is no property to stretch horizontally.

## *but,*

you can concatenate multiple fields in same text field to achieve your desired result.

```
${field1} + " " + ${field2}
```

**full jrxml for textField**

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6757386c-10c7-451f-bb1a-97951697d782"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[${field1} + " " + ${field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Just discovered Markup properties which solves most of my problems, I can do even <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>" + ${field1} + "</b> " + ${field2}]]></textFieldExpression>, thx

Comment: Thanks this worked.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it is not possible to stretch fields horizontally.

As you can see, `isStretchWithOverflow` causes the field to stretch vertically only.

The other option you mention, `float` position refers to... well... position. If one of the field on top stretches vertically or disappears, then all field below it, with position set to `float` will be moved up or down accordingly.

I've tried to achieve this myself for a long time but eventually gave up, as it is most likely not possible.

In some cases, an acceptable solution would be to place multiple field with different sizes on each other. Then, based on the texts length, you show only one of them.